# I'm getting this response but can't identify the problem - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: navigator.getGamepads is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and so don't really know where to go.. Here is the code which falls over right at the start.

```
async function updateControls() {
    const gamepad = navigator.getGamepads()[0];

    if (gamepad != undefined) {

        gpConf.buttons.padUp = gamepad.buttons[12].value
        gpConf.buttons.padDown = gamepad.buttons[13].value
        gpConf.buttons.padLeft = gamepad.buttons[14].value
        gpConf.buttons.padRight = gamepad.buttons[15].value

        //setting axes
        gamepad.axes.forEach((value, index) => {
            gpControls.axes[index] = exponentiate(value)
        });

        //setting paddles
        gpControls.paddles.left = Number(gamepad.buttons[6].value.toFixed(3))
        gpControls.paddles.right = Number(gamepad.buttons[7].value.toFixed(3))
        gpControls.buttons.L1 = gamepad.buttons[4].value
        gpControls.buttons.R1 = gamepad.buttons[5].value
        gpControls.buttons.square = gamepad.buttons[2].value
        gpControls.buttons.triangle = gamepad.buttons[3].value

        setTimeout(() => {
            updateControls();
        }, 100);


        dispatch('car-control', gpControls)
        dispatch('car-conf', gpConf)
    }
}
```

I've googled for help but haven't found a resolution. the error that comes up is:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: navigator.getGamepads is not a function"

I don't know if it is relevant but I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox.

Comment: Is the function `updateControls` in the frontend (browser) or backend (node) side? Are you overwriting `navigator` or `navigator.getGamepads` anywhere in your code? Have you tried logging the `navigator` object to check what functions it contains?

Comment: One possibility: Firefox only supports this method in a secure (https) connection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads#browser_compatibility.   Are you testing this locally, not using https?   (In several other browsers the user has to explicitly enable the feature; I wouldn't depend on this for a general audience until it's more broadly supported.)

Comment: you probably didn't import a third-party library to add properties to the navigator.

Comment: @aircraft According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads) navigator actually contains that function

Comment: "In several other browsers the user has to explicitly enable the feature" <-- ignore this bit, I was misreading the compatibility chart, sorry

Comment: On an unrelated side note, I would recommend using a single `setInterval` instead of calling `setTimeout` every time. (`const cancelIntervalID = setInterval(updateControls, 100)` outside `updateControls`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MDN docs on this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads), Firefox requires a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) to use it. That means you'll need to either be running the webpage from your own computer, or over HTTPS. You can also use other browsers such as Chrome or Edge for now, although they may require a secure context as well in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far - much appreciated! This is in the frontend and I'm running it locally..

Comment: @Nigel What local URL are you using to access the page (or are you opening the file directly)? What Firefox version are you using?

Comment: Hi Feathercrown - I'm using 192.168.1.87:1300 which is the local url of my PC - The firefox version I am currently using is 115.0.3 (64-bit) and I am getting the same result on Firefox Developer Edition 116.0b8 (64-bit)
I have a raspberry pi that streams video to port 1300 - the video works but the gamepad falls over.

Comment: @Nigel I think for Firefox to consider a local URL secure it needs to be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: how right you are ! :-)
Problem solved - thankyou very much.